# Coordinate Rings of Algebraic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let's take a smooth algebraic curve $C$ over a field $k$. We know that its coordinate ring $\mathcal{O}$ is a Dedekind domain.

Now, isomorphic curves should have isomorphic Dedekind domains attached to them, right? But I'm confused by the following example:

$$\begin{align}
C_1 &:= \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2 + y^2 - 1) \\
C_2 &:= \mathbb{P}_\mathbb{R}^1
\end{align}$$

As far as I can see:

1. $C_1$ is isomorphic to $C_2$ via the usual line intersection trick
2. $C_1$ has coordinate ring $\mathcal{O}_1 := \mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2 + y^2 - 1)$
3. $C_2$ has coordinate ring $\mathcal{O}_2 := \mathbb{R}[t]$
4. $\mathcal{O}_1$ is *not* isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_2$, because $\mathcal{O}_2$ has class number 1 whereas $\mathcal{O}_1$ has class number 2

(That $\mathcal{O}_1$ has class number 2 isn't obvious, but I'm pretty sure it's true because it was claimed on a couple of MathOverflow posts; the non-trivial ideal class corresponds to the Moebius strip line bundle, apparently.)

I can't quite see where my mistake is. I think it might be connected to some "affine vs. projective" issues. If one of you could shine some light on it, that would be great!

Comment: You are confusing the *set* $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{R})$ with the *scheme* $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$. The scheme is not affine. The notion of coordinate ring is primarily used for affine schemes as the ring of global functions on a projective scheme is a finite algebra over the underlying field. In particular, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are not isomorphic as schemes.

Comment: Thank you, the schemes being not isomorphic solves the mystery!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to talk about coordinate rings of non-affine varieties. The ring of global section of any projective variety over a field is a finite dimensional algebra over the base field. Your description of $C_2$ can't be correct.

Moreover, you are conflating schemes and their points over a field. The $\mathbb{R}$ -points of your $C_1$ and $C_2$ might be in bijection, even homeomorphic as topological spaces, but these two curves are not isomorphic as schemes. $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $\operatorname{Spec} B$ may easily have the same points over some field while not being isomorphic as affine schemes. This boils down to $\mathbb{R}$ not being algebraically closed.

Also, $\mathbb{R}[t]$ is a PID and hence has class number 1.

Comment: Thanks! Though I think under certain hypothesis it should make sense to speak about the coordinate ring of a projective variety. It's defined via the sections of a maximal open subset $U \subsetneq X$ or so, and different such $U$ should give you isomorphic rings. I just remember this from some AG notes I've read before. For the class number thing, there was just a typo in an index; $\mathcal{O}_1$ has class number 2.

Comment: @JohannBirnick This is not the coordinate ring, it's the field of rational functions, which is $\mathbb{R}(t)$ for $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$. Lots of algebraic varieties may have isomorphic fields of rational functions.

Comment: Right, it's the field rational functions! Thanks.